# How to create table in teradata that can be accessible by every user

Tags: teradata

I have a  use case where I need to create a table with 1000 columns and encrypt each column by a different user.
No granting access to every user is one way of doing things. but is there any space where I can create a table so that it is accessible by all user

Answer (score 2):

```
select 
  case when user_col=USER then value_col else null end encrypted_value 
from encrypted_table;
```

In this design you can set all encrypted values in a single column, instead of hundreds of them while adding more and more - as more users arrive.

Alternatively,

```
select 
  case when CURRENT_USER='<your_user_name>' then value_col
  else null end encrypted_col
from encrypted_table;
```

Comment: I've been having a lot of problems with `USER` since about 15.00 and have found `CURRENT_USER` much more reliable, especially users coming in through EXTUSER/LDAP.